# Which behavior to expect from jQuery find()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here's a Firebug session

```
>>> var e = $("<div>div-1<p>p-1</p></div><div>div-2</div><p>p-2</p>");
>>> e
[div, div, p]
>>> e.find('div')
[]
>>> e.find('p')
[p]
```

Isn't `e.find('div')` and `e.find('p')` supposed to return `[div, div]` and  `[p, p]` respectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that it is calling find on each element in the e, since e isn't one whole element. If you wrap e in another tag, ie:

```
var e = $("<div><div>div-1<p>p-1</p></div><div>div-2</div><p>p-2</script></div>");
```

then you get the behavior you wanted.

Alternatively if you don't wish to modify e you can use

```
 e.filter("p").add(e.find("p"));
```